# Django REST framework with nested DictField in MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using Django-nonrel with MongoDB. I have an issue on the serializer with my database data. Here are my model and serializer classes

```
class info(models.Model):
  price = DictField(EmbeddedModelField('data')

class data(models.Model):
  field_vol = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I have tested in Django shell and it works with storing data into the database (not serialised or deserialized). The data stored in database is shown as this:

```
{
  _id: blablabla,
  price: {
    '20121230': {
      field_vol: 123
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to get back the data by using serializer, it raises an issue on the fields in serializer.
Here is my current serializer class:

```
class dataSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = data


class infoSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  data = dataSerial()
  class Meta:
    model = info
    field = ('price')
```

As the price contains an outer dict and an inner dict. The error raises is related to serach for the 'field_vol' in price but nothing found. May I ask what should I do on letting the serializer searching keys and values in inner dict please?

** The key name, i.e. '20121230' is not a fixed key name, it increases according to the date of input.

I managed to get the serialised data in shell, and here is the structure:

```
infoSerial:
  price = dataSerial():
    field_vol = IntegerField()
```

However, when I get the infoSerial.data, it fails as it is searching for field_vol however I have a date Key before this field.

Another test for myself: I have tried to modify the price field into this way:

```
price = DictField(DictField(EmbeddedModelField('data')))
```

This looks like more legit than my previous one, as the actual storage contains nested dict. However, the error comes off when I am getting the infoSerial:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I truly believe that the key name in the outer dict is not passing through this function. Do I really need to do a lambda on the dataSerial and how should I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

With your serializers Django REST framework expects something similar to:

```
{
    'price': {
        'field_vol': 123
    }
}
```

Serializers won't take an ID as key.

You could possible alter the mongoldb response as follows and add the id to the fields:

```
{
    'price': {
        'id': '20121230',
        'field_vol': 123
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, as I have more than one price data to be stored into the database, setting id field wouldn't be useful for me.

I have think of using List storing Dict items, however it is not efficient when I need to get a data of specific date.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you should change the storage format. However, you can write some glue code between the data / validated_data and mongodb to fill the gap.

Comment: I am currently looking into .to_representation() function, see if I can do some rewrite on the part. However, I am wondering is there other way to get keys and values according to the data returned.

Answer (score 0):

The question has no answer, it is because when playing with DictField, the current libraries do not support assigning/defining the value type of each key.
By skipping the stage of defining every key in class, it works perfectly. The validation is never True when doing is_valid().

Hope there will be a update for DictField() to have definition of fields.